# Click handler is not triggered when target element has been moved

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

Consider the following  demo https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-pur1dt

I have reactive form control with sync validator and  error message shown below the field when it is invalidated.

Validation is triggered when control loses focus. Below the control there is a button that has a click handler. The problem is that when I click the button, control loses focus, validation happens, error message shown and  moves the button down. And supposedly this prevents click handler from executing. Any suggestions why this happens and how to fix the issue?

I've updated the demo with comments. Note: only button below the input will reproduce the issue. The title wont be updated after you click it for the first time.

Comment: the link you supplied seems to be working as expected; Both buttons call their click events as expected. The form validation seems to be working as expected onChange too.

Comment: One alternative is to bind [disable] property with the form like this `<button [disabled]="form.invalid" (click)="onClick($event)">click OK</button>`  If the form is invalid the button will be disabled

Comment: @joshvito, try to reload fro each click. you'll see

Comment: @DanielC that's not my case. The button is not related to form submission. its just some other component that makes control to lose focus.

Comment: reloading will just rebuild the app to its init state. I guess I am not fully following your problem. sorry. I agree with @Daniel C, if you want the buttons to be disabled when the form in invalid bind to the disabled property of the button

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue seem to relate to DOM events triggering order

According to MDN:

> The click event is fired when a pointing device button (usually a
>   mouse's primary button) is pressed and released on a single element.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/click

In the given example the element moves the moment you `blur` the input -- because the validation happens instantly, reveals the error and repositions the button.

Therefore mouse **is down when** while over the button, but when **its up** -- the button is repositioned. So `click` **wont be triggered on the button**

There are several options to workaround that:

- on `mousedown` delay the error reveal
- hide the error until both `mousedown` and `mouseup` happened, if `mousedown` happened on the button
- etc

Here's an example with `mousedown` event handling
https://jsfiddle.net/gjbgqqpo/

Hope this helps :)

Comment: that's exactly the explanation I was looking  for. Great!

Answer (score 4):

The problem was discussed in [issue #7113](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/7113) on GitHub. It is caused by the fact that validation is performed when the input field loses focus, before the click on the button has a chance to complete and trigger the `click` event.

A possible workaround is to use a flag to keep the message hidden while clicking the button is under way, as shown in [**this stackblitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-cjbybs). In the code below, the `isClicking` flag is set when clicking starts on the `mousedown` event, and it is reset when the `click` event completes.

```
<p #errorMsg [hidden]="(errorMsg.hidden && isClicking) || form.controls.name.valid || form.controls.name.untouched ">
    Invalid :)
</p>
<button (mousedown)="onMouseDown($event)" (click)="onClick2($event)">click NOT ok</button>
```

```
export class AppComponent {

  isClicking = false;
  ...

  onMouseDown(event) {
    this.isClicking = true;
    setTimeout(() => {
      // The click action began but was not completed after two seconds
      this.isClicking = false;
    }, 2000);
  }

  onClick2(event) {
    console.log(event);
    this.name = "NOT";
    this.isClicking = false;
  }
}
```

You can improve that solution by replacing the `setTimeout` with a procedure to capture the mouse in the `mousedown` event handler, and resetting `isClicking` when the capture is lost. It would account for the cases where the user leaves the button without completing the click.

Comment: I made a correction to my answer for clicks when the message is already displayed.

Comment: you can probably also add that this problem is not specific to Angular, but can also be easily reproduced with pure JS https://jsfiddle.net/f872ocbb/

Comment: @AngularInDepth.com - What is specific to Angular is that validation is triggered on the `blur` event, and that using validation is very standard (much more than handling the `blur` event). That makes the problem likely to happen in that framework. I am wondering: are there problems in Angular that cannot be reproduced in pure Javascript?

Comment: yes, framework specific errors like expressionchangedafteritwaschecked

Answer (score 0):

ok, i think I follow. You DO NOT want validation to happen when the lower button is clicked.

The reason validation is triggered is because of the `autofocus` on the form input. Angular "By default, the value and validity of a control updates whenever the value changes."  [See FormControl](https://angular.io/api/forms/FormControl). The control is changing `name.untouched` from `false` to `true`.

you can watch this happen if you add some extra debug bindings to your template.
e.g.

```
<hello name="{{ name }}"></hello>
<form [formGroup]="form">
    <input formControlName="name" autofocus>
    <button (click)="onClick($event)">click OK</button>
</form>
<pre>{{form.controls.name.valid}}</pre>
<pre>{{form.controls.name.untouched}}</pre>
<p [hidden]="form.controls.name.valid || form.controls.name.untouched ">
    Invalid :)
</p>
<button (click)="onClick2($event)">click NOT ok</button>
```

If you want to hide the error message when the user clicks the lower button, you should remove the `autofocus` or reset the validation of the form when `onClick2()` is called. Alternatively you can just show error message when the form has an error. Angular says `A control is untouched if the user has not yet triggered a blur event on it.` Clicking the lower button causes a blur event.

Why not just change your template binding on the error message to be

```
<p [hidden]="!form.controls.name.valid || form.controls.name.untouched">
    Invalid :)
</p>
```

Comment: no, the validation should be  triggered, but the click handler should be executed too. and it is not

Comment: Check that onClick2 is not executed for the  first time (after reload) at all

Comment: sorry, I realized that prev answer only worked after init load :/, so I editted the above

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution for this is to add `(mousedown)="false"` to your dismiss button. This way blur event won't happen, because focus event on your button will be canceled by your mousedown handler. In turn, this won't mark control as touched and your error won't show.

```
<button type="button" (click)="dismiss()" (mousedown)="false">Cancel</button>
```

Now for your submit button, you don't want to cancel the blur event, but you probably want to run some kind of validation logic on mousedown. Think about it this way, if the button has moved, that means there was an error in the form. What do you want to do when there is an error in the form? In my case, all I really wanna do is mark all controls as touched so that all validation errors will be shown.

```
<button type="submit" (mousedown)="form.markAllAsTouched()">Create</button>
```