# Button click not happening when button moves

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular

I'm using angular forms and have a simple login form with a submit button at the bottom of it. When an input field is blurred validation happens and if there is an error it is show underneath the input field and above the button. The problem is that the button is getting moved down when validation errors occur and are shown so the button click doesn't happen unless I click the very bottom of it.

Is there any slick fix to preserve the button click area, or a way to trigger click before the blur?

Here's the html, utilizes bootstrap4.

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row justify-content-center">
    <div class="col-sm-8 col-md-4">
      {{'LOGIN' | translate}}
      <form #form="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="login(form.valid, form.value)" [ngFormOptions]="{updateOn: 'blur'}" novalidate>

        <div class="form-group">
          <div class="input-group">
            <div class="input-group-prepend">
              <span class="input-group-text">
                <i class="fa fa-envelope"></i>
              </span>
            </div>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" ngModel name="email" #email="ngModel" id="inputEmail" placeholder="{{'EMAIL' | translate}}"
              pattern="[a-z0-9._%+-]+@[a-z0-9.-]+\.[a-z]{2,3}$" required>
          </div>
          <p class="text-danger" *ngIf="(form.submitted && email.invalid) || (email.invalid && (email.dirty || email.touched))">
            <span *ngIf="email.errors.pattern">
              Please enter valid email address.
            </span>
            <span *ngIf="email.errors.required">
              Email is required.
            </span>
          </p>

        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
          <div class="input-group">
            <div class="input-group-prepend">
              <span class="input-group-text">
                <i class="fa fa-key"></i>
              </span>
            </div>
            <input #password="ngModel" type="password" class="form-control" id="password" placeholder="{{'PASSWORD' | translate}}" name="password"
              ngModel minlength="8" required>
          </div>
          <p class="text-danger" *ngIf="(form.submitted && password.invalid) || (password.invalid && (password.dirty || password.touched))">
            <span *ngIf="password.errors.minlength">
              Password must be at least 8 characters.
            </span>
            <span *ngIf="password.errors.required">
              Password is required.
            </span>
          </p>
        </div>

        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">{{'LOGIN' | translate}}</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Provide some code in order for somebody to be able to help you.

Comment: You can find a workaround in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48011858/1009922).

Comment: @ConnorsFan this worked, thanks!

Comment: @rycirese - You are welcome. Feel free to upvote [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48011858/1009922). :-)